# Blocking queue implementation with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, queue

I implemented, somewhat closely based on [this implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128832/c11-blocking-queue-learning-exercise), a blocking queue with emphasis on filling up first. So if one producer and one consumer thread are using the queue, the producing queue gets prioritized.

```
// BQueue.hpp
//#pragma once
#ifndef _BQUEUE_HPP
#define _BQUEUE_HPP

#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

template <class T> class BQueue {
public:
  BQueue(size_t size);
  void push(T item);
  bool pop(T &item);
  /* ALTERNATIVE 1
  void push(std::unique_ptr<T> item);
  bool pop(std::unique_ptr<T> &item);
  */

private:
  std::mutex _mutex;
  //std::queue<std::unique_ptr<T>> _queue; // ALTERNATIVE 1
  std::queue<T> _queue;
  size_t _size;
  std::condition_variable _condition_full;
  std::condition_variable _condition_empty;
};
#include "BQueue.hxx"
#endif // _BQUEUE_HPP
```

implementation

```
// BQueue.hxx
#include "BQueue.hpp"
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

template <class T> BQueue<T>::BQueue(size_t size) : _size(size) {}

// ALTERNATIVE 1
// template <class T> void BQueue<T>::push(std::unique_ptr<T> item) {
template <class T> void BQueue<T>::push(T item) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
  while (_queue.size() >= _size) {
    _condition_full.wait(lock, [&]() { return (_queue.size() < _size); });
  }
  _queue.push(std::move(item));
  // _queue.push(item); // ALTERNATIVE 1

  // if queue is full, notify consumation part first
  if (_queue.size() >= _size) {
    _condition_empty.notify_one();
  }
  _condition_full.notify_one();
}

// template <class T> bool BQueue<T>::pop(T &item) {
template <class T> bool BQueue<T>::pop(T &item) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
  while (_queue.empty()) {
    if (!_condition_empty.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1),
                                   [&]() { return !_queue.empty(); })) {
      // waited too long for input.
      return false;
    }
  }
  item = std::move(_queue.front());
  // item = _queue.fron(); // ALTERNATIVE
  _queue.pop();
  /* THIS FOLLOWING CODE MAY BE NEEDED;
   * KEEP IT IN CASE
   * _condition_empty.notify_one();
   * // if queue is empty, notify production
   * if (_queue.empty()) { //*/
  _condition_full.notify_one();
  // assert(_queue.size() < _size); //*/
  return true;
}
```

main

```
// alternatively: class Resource
struct Resource {
  int x;
};

int main() {
  BQueue<std::unique_ptr<struct Resource>> q{40};
  //BQueue<struct Resource> q_alternative1[40};

  std::unique_ptr<struct Resource> res1{new struct Resource};
  res1->x = 42;
  q.push(std::move(res1));

  q.push(std::move(std::unique_ptr<struct Resource>{new struct Resource}));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    std::unique_ptr<struct Resource> res{new struct Resource};
    res->x = i;
    q.push(std::move(res));
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    q.pop(res1);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I came across the question of resource handling. What does make more sense? Using the shown code or implement the whole thing using `std::unique_ptr` where necessary (see ALTERNATIVE 1)? `std::move` even works with non-resource wrapped types, apparently.

And, is the main function leak-free or did I miss anything? Does it work for `shared_ptr` types as well, or do I have to specialize because of `pop(T item &)` being a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if one producer and one consumer thread are using the queue, the producing queue gets prioritized.

I don't see anything in your code that corresponds to this sentence in your explanation. I think you have *no* "prioritization" going on here. The only thing determining which threads get to run when is the OS thread scheduler. And there's nothing at the algorithm level that could be described as "priorities"; this isn't like a rwlock where one side can "starve" the other. Contrariwise — each side here is *"feeding"* the other!

---

```
std::unique_ptr<struct Resource> res1{new struct Resource};
```

Two or three things about this line:

- Don't use raw `new` and `delete`; use `std::make_unique` here instead.
- Don't Repeat Yourself: use `auto` to avoid repetition here.
- In C++, writing `struct` (or `class` or `union`) in a type-name is not idiomatic.

Thus this line should become:

```
auto res1 = std::make_unique<Resource>();
```

and your `main` routine in total becomes:

```
int main() {
    BQueue<std::unique_ptr<Resource>> q{40};
    q.push(std::make_unique<Resource>(42));
    q.push(std::make_unique<Resource>());
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        q.push(std::make_unique<Resource>(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        std::unique_ptr<Resource> res1;
        q.pop(res1);
    }
}
```

Writing `return 0;` at the end of `main` is unnecessary and unidiomatic (*unless* you want to be explicit because you return a non-zero value by some other codepath).

---

About `unique_ptr` inside the container versus outside: Instinctively prefer abstractions that are *composable*. So, if your options are:

- create `BQueue<T>` that deals internally in `std::unique_ptr<T>`, or
- create `BQueue<T>` that deals internally in `T`,

you should obviously prefer the latter. As a bonus, this means that your code will be useful ("reusable") even for people who are still stuck on `boost::unique_ptr` — they won't have to switch all their code from `boost` to `std` just to use your queue class.

---

```
while (_queue.size() >= _size) {
  _condition_full.wait(lock, [&]() { return (_queue.size() < _size); });
}
```

This loop is extremely confusing. You're looping with one condition outside and a different condition in the inner lambda. I strongly recommend removing one or the other of these loops. Specifically, I would remove the inner loop.

```
while (_queue.size() >= _size) {
  _condition_full.wait(lock);
}
```

The nice thing about removing the *inner* loop (as above) is that it's easily readable by a non-expert (say, someone coming from Java, C#, or Python). But if your target audience is C++ experts, this would also be okay:

```
_condition_full.wait(lock, [&]() { return (_queue.size() < _size); });
```

---

Your condition variables have mildly confusing names, IMO. Is `_condition_full` the thing I should *wait on* when the queue is full? Or is it the thing that gets *notified* when the queue is full? A little thought shows that it must be the former; but I don't like thinking, even a little bit. :)

---

Notice that this line —

```
_queue.push(std::move(item));
```

— runs under the mutex lock. If the item's move-constructor does something sketchy, this could be dangerous.

If you generalize your `BQueue` far enough that the user-programmer is allowed to customize the underlying container (e.g. change `std::queue<T>` to `std::queue<T, std::list<T, A>>`), then be aware that the user-defined *memory allocator* will also be running under the mutex lock. This probably isn't a problem at your current level of caring-about-metaprogrammy-bits, but it's something to consider.

---

```
if (!_condition_empty.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1),
                               [&]() { return !_queue.empty(); })) {
  // waited too long for input.
  return false;
}
```

This (a function that blocks, but only for 1 second) is weird and dangerous. Don't do this.

If you want a `pop` function, write one. If you want a `try_pop` function (that can fail if the queue is empty), write one. If you want a `try_pop_for` function (that can fail by timing out), write one. But what you did was

- write a `try_pop_for_1s` function (?!)
- misname it `pop` (?!)

---

```
/* THIS FOLLOWING CODE MAY BE NEEDED;
 * KEEP IT IN CASE
 * _condition_empty.notify_one();
```

I *believe* this code is not needed. Consider:

- The queue is empty. Thread C1 enters `pop` and blocks on `_condition_empty`.
- Thread C2 enters `pop` and blocks on `_condition_empty`.
- Thread P enters `push`, adds an item to the queue, and notifies-one on `_condition_empty`.
- Thread P enters `push` again, adds a second item, and notifies-one on `_condition_empty`.

At this point, if either thread C1 or C2 is still waiting, it's a bug in the standard library. They should both be awake and waiting their turns to grab the mutex lock and process one item each off of the queue.

Similarly, the `_condition_full.notify_one()` at the end of `push` should not be needed, because if you've got two threads waiting on `_condition_full`, you might as well wait for the second `pop` before you unblock the second producer thread.

So:

```
template <class T>
void BQueue<T>::push(T item) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
  _condition_full.wait(lock, [&]() { return (_queue.size() < _size); });
  _queue.push(std::move(item));  // DANGER: running user code under a lock
  _condition_empty.notify_one();  // the queue is no longer empty
}

template <class T>
bool BQueue<T>::pop(T &item) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
  if (_condition_empty.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1),
                                 [&]() { return !_queue.empty(); })) {
    item = std::move(_queue.front());  // DANGER: running user code under a lock
    _queue.pop();  // DANGER: running user code under a lock
    _condition_full.notify_one();  // the queue is no longer full
    return true;
  }
  // waited too long for input; the queue is still empty
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, although I have changed the code already quite a bit, there was still much to learn from your input.
I overcome a lot of your trivial criticims like new/delete, variable names, composability. The very interesting bits like try_pop, loops you mentioned, I still struggle with.. Probably need some time to wrap my head around these. In any case, thanks.

Comment: Care to explain the danger about push(std::move(..))? Is it because I did not specify is_no_throw_constructible or similar? whats the scenario that push(std::move(...)) can become a problem? Would just limiting it is_trivially_constructible be safer?

Comment: "`push(std::move(...))` runs under the mutex lock. If the item's move-constructor does something sketchy, this could be dangerous." For example, deadlock: The code inside our item's move-constructor attempts to take a global non-recursive lock on some mutex `m`, which is already held by some other thread which is currently waiting on `this->_mutex`. Or, silly example, if the move-constructor contains `sleep(10)`, no other thread will be able to push or pop anything for 10 seconds! This is a special low-stakes case of "it's inappropriate to run untrusted code in a privileged environment."

Comment: Constraining `T` to be trivially move-constructible, trivially move-assignable, and trivially destructible would indeed remove the danger from all three `// DANGER:` comments in my rewrite above, as far as I can tell. Of course then you couldn't use your queue to store `unique_ptr`s or `string`s...

Comment: I see. C++ is hard to understand, but getting feedback like this is really helpful, cheers.